# Marsupial blackletter difficulty

Tags: inscription, transliteration, paleography

I believe I have all of this except one word (please correct any errors):

> Reperitur hic animal habens reserva_____ quo suos pullos secum portat et eos uon nisi lactandi tempore emittit. Tale regi Hispanie Granale oblatum est.

Secondarily,
 1. Why the macron in “oblatū”?
 2. Why “anīal”?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Lorenz Fries, 1525]

Comment: I guess the macrons abbreviate a following “m”.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! This is a lovely illustration.

Comment: Thank you. The illustration is from Lorenz Fries’s 1525 “Admiral’s Map”. Just a friendly family picnic and a gigantic, incredibly buff opossum…

I find on the verso a description normally credited to Simon Grynaeus in 1532: "Christophorus natione Italicus, patria Genuensis, gente Columba…" I’m a little mystified by “gente Columba”.

Comment: A 'gens' is "a family consisting of individuals who shared the same nomen and who claimed descent from a common ancestor" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gens. I looked up the quote and apparently there is a variation with 'gente Columbus,' which makes more sense in context (https://books.google.nl/books?id=HD-nO-wmOcAC&pg=PA20). So: "Christopher, by nation Italian, by fatherland Genovese, by family 'Columban,' i.e. of the Columbus family.

Comment: @Cerberus I believe I saw Marsupial Blackletter Difficulty open for Nirvana back in 93. Thought they had promise.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: "Open for"? As in, a concert hall that opens for a band? Or is this about the well known band Marsupial Blackletter Difficulty.

Comment: @Cerberus A band opening for another, i.e., playing before them ;-)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Ahh, in that sense. You may very well be right, although I think they were touring Antarctica around that time.

Answer (score 16):

The word is *reservaculum*, "something used to keep things in", from *reservo* "keep (back)". I believe this word is used to describe the pouch of marsupials in [similar texts](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-22703-6_2) from that period. Praesumably, this was before the word *marsupial* was invented, which is derived from Latin *marsupium*, "pouch".

Incidentally, you have *uon* where it should be *non*.

A plain horizontal mark above a letter normally indicates that a nasal consonant (*m* or *n*) has been omitted, in Mediaeval or later manuscript, in languages like Dutch, German, or Latin. Alternatively (but not in this text), it can be used as a general mark of abbreviation.

Note that the mark above the first *u* in *reservacŭlum* is a different sign. A mark that looks like ˘ or even a short diagonal line or semicircle can be used to indicate that the letter below it is a *u* or *v*, in order to avoid confusion with *n* or other letters.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the detailed response and corrections. I suspected “reservaculum”, but did not find it in dictionaries; glad to have it confirmed.

Comment: Almost got a +1 sola "praesumably"

Answer (score 8):

I can answer the second part, at least. That's a tilde *ĩ*, not a macron *ī*, and it's one of the most common scribal abbreviations, representing a following *N* or *M*. So *anĩal*, *tẽpore*, *oblatũ* = *animal*, *tempore*, *oblatum*.

This is where the modern tilde used in Spanish and Portuguese comes from: Latin *annum* > *anno* > Spanish *año* "year". It originated as a small "N" written above the letter, and eventually got simplified into the squiggle you see here.